# read value after question mark contain in htaccess parameter in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am doing url rewriting using .htaccess file. My .htaccess file containes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ edit_tutorial.php?tutorial_title=$1 [NC,L]
```

So my url looks like : 
`www.xxxx.com/tutorials/abc-fdfg S11wagfgdrm bedf-dats fd? Not:so fast`.

`"abc-fdfg S11wagfgdrm bedf-dats fd? Not:so fast"` is my tutorial title which contains colon, question mark, hyphen, numbers. I want to write rewrite rule for it. And I want special characters too. How can I write rule for it. Please Help.

And I am getting an issue while I am trying to read the title using `$_REQUEST['tutorial_title']` I am getting value like: `abc-fdfg S11wagfgdrm bedf-dats fd`. I am not able to read value after `?` mark. Please Help.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([\[\]=,\?&@~\{\}\+'\.*!™`A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ edit_tutorial.php?tutorial_title=$1 [QSA,L] . I tried this but its not working. Its giving 500 error.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, My rewrite url is like this : example.com/subject/tutorials/Docker_Swarm_beats_Kubernetes?_Not_so_fast. 
I am not getting the value after question mark. For example in above 'Docker_Swarm_beats_Kubernetes?_Not_so_fast' is my tutorial title. When I used $_REQUEST['tutorial_title'] then I am getting tutorial_title as 'Docker_Swarm_beats_Kubernetes'. What should I do to get tutorial_title as 'Docker_Swarm_beats_Kubernetes?_Not_so_fast'. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule with `QUERY_STRING` being captured from `THE_REQUEST`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tutorials/[^/?]+/?(\?\S*)?\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^tutorials/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?tutorial_title=$1%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What to do if my some tutorial title not contains ? mark. Because if my tutorial title not contains ? mark it auto appends ? to my title.

Comment: For example if my link is : example.com/subject/tutorials/abc_def. 
then I am getting tutorial title as : abc_def? like this in my $_REQUEST['tutorial_title'] variable. if I used ?%{QUERY_STRING}. It working fine in if my title contains ? mark.

Comment: Since that is inside php code, you can easily trim last `?` character using trim function.

Comment: Ya.. But but one of my tutorial title contains question marks at end of title.